# TypeError: Cannot read property 'ImageAnnotatorClient' of undefined

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-vision

I'm trying Google-cloud/vision to detect handwriting text recognition in image,(pdf). I have been facing error message from last 6 hours. Please suggest me if I have to change anything in the code.

```
    'use strict';

function detectHandwritingOCR(fileName) {
  const vision = require('@google-cloud/vision').v1p3beta1;
  const fs = require('fs');
  // Creates a client
  const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();

  const request = {
    image: {
    content: fs.readFileSync(fileName),
    },
    feature: {
    languageHints: ['en-t-i0-handwrit'],
    },
};
 client
   .documentTextDetection(request)
  .then(results => {
     const fullTextAnnotation = results[0].fullTextAnnotation;
     console.log(`Full text: ${fullTextAnnotation.text}`);
})
.catch(err => {
  console.error('ERROR:', err);
});
 // [END vision_handwritten_ocr_beta]
```

}

```
console.log(detectHandwritingOCR('C:/Users/sandrpa/Downloads/handwrittenimage.jpg'));
```

The error message that I get is :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'ImageAnnotatorClient' of undefined.**

Comment: Why are you adding .v1p3beta1 when requiring? This probably is the issue.

Comment: when I remove v1p3beta1 I face different error "TypeError: vision.ImageAnnotatorClient is not a constructor".

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to replicate this scenario; however, I was able to execute the almost exact code without problem. I recommend you to verify you have installed the latest [Vision Client library](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/libraries#client-libraries-install-nodejs) version, as well as [explicitly specify the **auth credentials** within your code](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#obtaining_and_providing_service_account_credentials_manually) in order to discard any authentication issues.

```
'use strict';

function detectHandwritingOCR(fileName) {
  const vision = require('@google-cloud/vision').v1p3beta1;
  const fs = require('fs');
  // Creates a client
  const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient({keyFilename: '<CREDENTIALS_FILE_NAME>.json'});

  const request = {
    image: {
    content: fs.readFileSync(fileName),
    },
    feature: {
    languageHints: ['en-t-i0-handwrit'],
    },
};
 client
   .documentTextDetection(request)
  .then(results => {
     const fullTextAnnotation = results[0].fullTextAnnotation;
     console.log(`Full text: ${fullTextAnnotation.text}`);
})
.catch(err => {
  console.error('ERROR:', err);
});
 // [END vision_handwritten_ocr_beta]
}

console.log(detectHandwritingOCR('./<IMAGE_FILE_NAME>'));
```